# Images from ImageField doesn't load in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, imagefield

I'm creating a real-estate agency website. Each offer has several photos and one of them, after marking it in the admin panel as the main photo, should be displayed at the index page but unfortunately it isn't.

I think that the problem is either in `views.py` or in `index.html`. `Settings.py` and `urls` seems to be fine because I have the access to the given image by entering the exact url of the image in a browser (e.g. .../media/photos/name_of_the_image.jpg) - then the image is shown in a browser.

Models.py:

```
class Offer(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    floor_space = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Offer nb %s" % (self.id)


class OfferImage(models.Model):

    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, related_name='images')
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', blank=True, null=True)
    main_image = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views.py:

```
def index(request):
    category_list = Category.objects.all
    latest_offers = Offer.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]

    context_dict = {
        'categories': category_list,
        'latest_offers': latest_offers,
                    }

    return render(request, 'cardom/index.html', context_dict)
```

Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('cardom.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns(
        'django.views.static',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)',
         'serve',
         {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )

if not settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Index.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<table class="table">
    {% for offer in latest_offers %}
    <tr><th>{{offer.category}}</th></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="{{ offer.images.url }}" height="120" width="200" alt="error"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>{{offer.city}} {{offer.district}} {{offer.floor_space}} {{offer.price}} </td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table><br />
</div>
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
{{ offer.images.url }}
```

what you get is a blank string as `offer.images` is a `RelatedManager` and it does not have an url attribute.

You should retrieve the corresponding image either using a dedicated Manager or another query in your view:

```
main_images = offer.images.filter(main=True)
try:
    image = main_images[0]
except:
    image = None # Or whatever you want
```

You can also to avoid this to add an additional attribute main_image to your Offer model (but you will have to write the corresponding logic for admin).

Comment: I added main_image and it is a simple way to make it work, thanks